# Buy One Get One Half Price in PHP shopping cart total

Tags: php, shopping-cart

I am creating a shopping cart in PHP and a particular item is buy one get one half price. When the user purchases the item, I would get like the offer to be deducted from the total but I'm stuck on how I would do this mathematically.

So far I have something like this in a if loop getting data from database:

```
$total = $total+($arraycart['Price']*$quantity);
```

Then I think it will be something along the lines of:

```
if ($arraycart['Item'] == "A1" and $quantity > 1) {
//calculate here buy one get one half price
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `$total = $total+((0.5 * $arraycart['Price']) * $quantity);`?

Comment: @u_mulder that would add half price of everything. They already are calculating the full price times quantity. You wouldn't want to add another half price on top of that. You would more likely want to subtract half price for half of the quantity like: `$total = $total - ($arraycart['Price'] * 0.5 * floor($quantity / 2))` which would remove half price for half of the items. This is of course after you do your `$total` math.

Comment: I just gave a hint. Checking when to apply it is OP's task

Comment: @u_mulder I only mentioned it because it is technically wrong. If I had 10 things at $1 each, I wouldn't want to add an additional `0.5 * $price * $quantity` making my total $15. If this were looping over quantity and adding to a total sum, then yes, adding `0.5 * $price` for every other item is fine.

Comment: I would use another method to achieve the goal. I would put the discounts into a separate array, and then I would use that array to determine whether the discount should still apply or not. You're complicating things by putting it all together.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Thank you! Your solution was simple and worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$total = 0;
$arraycart['Price'] = 10;
$arraycart['Item'] = 'A1';

$quantity = 3; // change item quantity here

if ($arraycart['Item'] == "A1" and $quantity % 2 == 0 ) {
    //calculate here buy one get one half price
    $real = ($quantity/2)*$arraycart['Price'];
    $half = ($quantity/2)*($arraycart['Price']/2);

    $total = $real+$half;

} else {
    $quantity = $quantity-1;

    $real = ($quantity/2)*$arraycart['Price'];
    $half = ($quantity/2)*($arraycart['Price']/2);

    $total = $real+$half+$arraycart['Price'];

}

echo $total;
?>
```

Comment: You are giving a 50% discount on everything after the first, not just buy one get one which would mean that for every one purchased at full price, the next is half off. If the quantity was 5, you are giving a discount on 4 of those when it should only be on 2.

Comment: add one more and condition in if ( and $quantity < 3)  or any other trick :)

Comment: so if you order 4, you don't get a discount?

Comment: Ok means if your product is in pair than original + half price will be count other wise you will count original price. I changed the above code according to your requirement . Hope it will help to understand you :)