# How can I modify this function code to work?

Tags: php

I found this code here at [Buy One Get One Half Price in PHP shopping cart total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40918048/buy-one-get-one-half-price-in-php-shopping-cart-total) and I am trying to modify it for an event attendee to get a 40% discount on every additional attendee they register for. If Attendee A with a family of 4 sign up, Attendee A will pay full price, each of the remaining 3 attendee will get 40% discount on their tickets.

I have been searching various online forums with no help until I found one here but it's quite close to what I am looking for but a bit different. So far, my code has not worked and I will appreciate some input.

```
$total = 0;
$ticket['Price'] = 10;
$ticket['Item'] = 1;

$ticket_no = 3; 

if ($ticket['Item'] == "tickets" and $ticket_no % 2 == 0 ) {
    //calculate here buy one get each additional at 40% discount
    $eventPrice = ($ticket_no)*$ticket['Price'];
    $discountPrice = ($ticket_no)*($ticket['Price’]*.4);

    $total = $eventPrice+$discountPrice;

} else {
    $ticket_no = $ticket_no-1;

    $eventPrice = ($ticket_no)*$ticket['Price'];
    $discountPrice = ($ticket_no)*($ticket['Price’]*.4);

    $total = $eventPrice+$discountPrice+$ticket['Price'];

}

echo $total;
?>
```

Comment: There is a typo here `$ticket['Price’]`. It uses incorrect quote character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If Attendee A with a family of 4 sign up, Attendee A will pay full price, each of the remaining 3 attendee will get 40% discount on their tickets.

You can use this code and modify it based on your use case.

```
$total = 0;
$ticket['Price'] = 10;

// discount
$discount = 0.4; 

// I assume this is the number of tickets of a family of 4 signup
$ticket_no = 4; 

// set current price as the total for "Attendee A"
$total = $ticket['Price'];

// then decrement the ticket_no so it is now 3.
$ticket_no--;

// make sure ticket no is greater than 0; so we can calculate for the remaining
if ($ticket_no > 0){
    $discountedPrice = $ticket['Price'] - ($ticket['Price'] * $discount);

    $total += ($ticket_no) * $discountedPrice;
}

echo $total;
```

So the expected total here is $28.

Comment: thanks but I am assuming the total should be $28. One person will pay $10, each of the other 3 will pay $6 ($18 total). So the total for a family of 4 would be $28.

Comment: You're right, it should be $28. I will update the above.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$total = 0;
$ticket['Price'] = 10;
$ticket['Item'] = "tickets";
$ticket_no = 4; //number of signup
if ($ticket['Item'] == "tickets" and $ticket_no > 1 ) {
// if more than 1 signup ($ticket_no > 1)
    $eventPrice = $ticket['Price']; //first is 100% price
    $discountPrice = ($ticket_no - 1)*($ticket['Price']*6/10); // the rest is 60% (40% discount)
    $total = $eventPrice+$discountPrice;
} else {
// if only 1 signup
    $total = $ticket['Price'];
}
echo $total;
?>
```